# How do I deploy a c# REST-Api

Tags: c#, api, deployment

Hello sorry if this is a copy of another question. I have from school learned how to develope a backend in c#, but never how to deploy it remotly. I am well aware I can run it on from my pc at home, but it's not the solution im looking to use. Anybody know some links, videoes etc on how to do so?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will most probably use something like IIS to deploy it from your own pc, or on some cloud hosting platform to deploy it remotely.

What you have to research is how to deploy an ASP.NET Web application.